# Create web service based on a known XSD in C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, xsd

I often have to create a soap web service which needs to conform to certain documentation. In particular it is often some OTA flavour. (open travel alliance)

For example the service needs to receive OTA_HotelRateAmountNotifRQ and respond with a OTA_HotelRateAmountNotifRS. Generally the syntax of those messages can be downloaded as .xsd:
http://www.opentravel.org/2004A/OTA_HotelRateAmountNotifRQ.xsd

What I would like to do is simplify the process of creating such a service (right now I'm using XDocument and analyze/create the XML by hand).

So assuming I have access to particular XSD files, how can I automatically create corresponding code/classes, wrap them up in SOAP and use as a basis for a web service?

I hope the question makes some sense, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the XSD to model your WSDL. Then import your WSDL into Visual Studio. This is called the top down or WSDL first approach.

If you dont have a decent WSDL editor such as Altova XML Spy or Liquid XML I would suggest you invest in one as it will make this rather easy.

See [Walkthrough: Designing Application Systems by Using a Top-Down Approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386046(v=vs.90).aspx) for an example.